# Node "JavaScript heap out of memory" - increasing max-old-space-size doesn't solve

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, amazon-ec2, memory-management

Have an ec2 instance running Node 14.15 (m5zn.2xlarge) through pm2

Sometimes when it receives many queries at once, I get the following error.

```
24-07 16:03:33.533: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
24-07 16:03:33.534:  1: 0x8daaa0 node::Abort() [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.534:  2: 0x8daaec  [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker-server/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.534:  3: 0xad79ae v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.535:  4: 0xad7be4 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.535:  5: 0xece9e2  [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.535:  6: 0xede2df v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.536:  7: 0xea63c5  [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.536:  8: 0xeadd3b v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.537:  9: 0xff8bf3 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.537: 10: 0xad4f84 v8::internal::String::Flatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.537: 11: 0xae3530 v8::String::Utf8Length() const [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.538: 12: 0x8f3586  [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.538: 13: 0xb6114f  [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.538: 14: 0xb61ca5 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node /home/ubuntu/app/src/worker/index.js]
24-07 16:03:33.538: 15: 0x35fedb95be1d
```

I've tried increasing max-old-space-size incrementally little by little, but nothing seems to work at all. Here is the output of v8.getHeapStatistics():

```
{
  total_heap_size: 6041600,
  total_heap_size_executable: 524288,
  total_physical_size: 5368096,
  total_available_size: 25815713408,
  used_heap_size: 4013080,
  heap_size_limit: 25820135424,
  malloced_memory: 8192,
  peak_malloced_memory: 582752,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 2,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}
```

Is there anything else I can do here to try to avoid these errors happening? They only happen sometimes, so generally it's able to handle the requests being thrown at it. So I would have figured that almost quadrupling the max-old-space-size would've helped, but doesn't seem to be making any difference.

Comment: after some digging, it may have something to do with the way I'm starting the process with PM2. Currently doing this: "NODE_ENV=production NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=24576 pm2 start ./src/worker/index.js --interpreter babel-node --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS' --node-args='--max-old-space-size=24576'" but I now think that this may not actually be setting the max-old-space-size properly?